# jquery ui loading dialog on click only firing once

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an anchor tag on my page that toggles between active and cancelled entities.  Only one link is showen at a time depending on what the user wants to see. I use ajax to replace the html with either active info or cancelled info. See below.

The problem that I'm having is that when the user clicks the link the loading dialog should be displayed, but the dialog is only being displaying on the first click and not the subsequent clicks. This is only happening in Chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#showCancelled, a#showActive").live("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog('open');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: Success,
            error: Error
        });
    });

    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 50,
         width: 400,
         modal: true,
         closeOnEscape: false,
         draggable: false,
         resizable: false
    });
});

function Success (data, status) {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog('close');
    $("body").html(data);
}
```

html

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Loading...">
    <p><img src="../images/busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT** -
I have changed my code to below from suggestions and wrapped the content I want updated with a dummy `<div>`. But now the dialog doesn't open at all and nothing is displayed when the content is updated in IE7.

```
$("a#showCancelled, a#showActive").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $link = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog('open');
    $("#dummy").load($link + " #dummy");
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: Works now, must have been a browser caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `<body>` element's contents with this:

```
$("body").html(data);
```

This will destroy any dialog or anything inside the page really...did you want to stick the response in another container perhaps, something like this?

```
$("#result").html(data);
```

If not you either need to re-run the dialog creation piece after setting the `<body>` contents:

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({ ...options... });
```

Or create it on each click, and call `.dialog('destroy')` first, though this is a bit more wasteful.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, I guess the problem would be then that the ajax request is sending back a whole html page. Is there a way to extract a specific div out of the data and place it in the result div? Maybe using the .load?

Comment: @Randall - Yep, you can do `.load("page.html #content")` for example, just put a space and selector after the URL.

Comment: Well it's not a static .html page per se, that is why I need to return it using the .ajax method. Something like .load(data#content #content) would be how I would need to use it.

Comment: @Randall - Oh any URL works just add the selector afterwards, e.g. `.load("myAjaxPage.php #content")`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Seems like i'm having another problem with it now. Maybe re-create the dialog everytime might be the way to go. Although like you said it does seem a bit wasteful. :)